# How to set number of lines of WKInterfaceTextField

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, watchos-7

I'm using watchOS 7.0. I have added a text field to a scene. I'm trying to allow the text field to wrap it's text over more than 1 line so that it isn't cut off. There are tons of posts about setting the number of lines property to zero to achieve this. However I don't see this property anywhere. Has it been removed or am I missing something? I'm using Xcode 12.0.1

[image]

Comment: The number of lines property is for labels, not text fields. I'm afraid this is not possible. (Not an answer because I am not sure)

Comment: Yes, right the number of line property is for labels only not for textfields. Same as UIKit or  AppKit.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the info! I actually didn't realise the other posts were talking about labels, and I was using a text field.